# Double switch wiring

Tags: lighting, bathroom

I replaced an old double switch with a new one and now nothing turns on. Both are 15a 125v. Looking at the old switch : on the left, two white wires going to two gold screws above/below each other; on the right, two black wires going to two gold screws above/below each other; and one ground soldered to the bottom of the unit on metal (no screw).

The new double switch has gold screws on the left, and black screws on the right, with on ground screw below the black screws.

I put the black wires to the black screws and the white to the gold. Then put the green ground wire to the ground screw. Now nothing works. So I put the white wires to the black screws and the black wire to the gold. Still no change. Should I put the black wires back to the black screws but flip them (from top to bottom) same with white?[image][image][image]

Comment: On the old switch, were any tabs broken off? *I would expect "yes"*.

Comment: yes I just dug the old switch from the trash and looked on the right side(where the black wires were) it does look like something was snapped off in the middle.

Comment: The other side is already split (or it would defeat the purpose lol).  I think you're on the trail to a solution now!

Comment: Ok, so I will return the wires to how they were (mirrored on the old switch) then break that tab off.

Comment: The main thing is one cable needs to feed the top switch, and the other cable needs to feed the bottom switch.  A cable has 1 black + 1 white.

Comment: Can you post a photo looking into the back of the box please?

Comment: I added a new photo. Hopefully it helps. I returned the wires to their original place. Black to black posts and white to gold posts. Then broke that clip off and still nothing.